# Is there any issue with vanity addresses from a security p.o.v

Tags: security, vanity-id

this seems like a cool concept : https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-vanity-address

with this i can generate custom addresses starting with custom words, but is there a security risk for generating the program id this way ?

Answer (score 4):

No, It's the same as any randomly generated Keypairs.
Some security precautions you should follow very very carefully like:

- Keeping the corresponding secret key in a very very secure cage.
- Use a secure server/computer to generate Keypairs.

Comment: this isn't entirely true.  fixing public key bits limits the private key search space

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Technically, fixing bits in the output reduces the input search space. In the case of ed25519 it is still quite infeasible as this is effectively a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) on SHA512

Comment: but after the program is deployed it does not matter does it ?

Comment: so long as you strictly use the keypair for the program address reservation and destroy it afterwards, it should be fine.  there was nothing about program deployment in the OP though, so if there's a new question, create a new post

Answer (score 1):

Once you deploy a program using that uses the generated vanity address, it should not matter.

After the address is "taken" but a program, it will have an "update authority" stored on-chain. Only this "update authority" wallet will have the ability to publish a new version of the program, and effectively be the only address that can change the program.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is the same as a randomly generated Keypair, only harder/longer to obtain depending on how many characters you intend to grind.

Answer (score 0):

The only security issue is if someone accesses the server you generated the key pair file on.

Comment: once deployed even if the private key of a program id json file leaks its useless no ?

Comment: Is that any different from someone accessing the server where a keypair was generated at random?

Comment: Yes, once the program is deployed the only key pair that matters is the key pair of the upgrade authority.